# Is there a phrasal verb that describes going around, engaging in pointless chores just to kill some time because you don't know what to do?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, definition

Not "to procrastinate", maybe a verb that emphasizes more on the movement characteristic of the action

Comment: “Kill time” is a valid phrasal verb.

Comment: [Busy work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_work): *activity that is undertaken to pass time and stay busy but in and of itself has no actual value*, is pretty close, but it's a noun (phrase).

Answer (score 2):

***puttering around*** fits very well. It may be US-specific, though.

[Definition from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/putter%20around):

> : to spend time in a relaxed way doing small jobs and other things
>   that are not very important
>
> // I didn't do much last weekend. I just puttered around.
>   // He spent his vacation puttering around the house/garden.

Comment: I think a good UK/Australian/etc equivalent would be "pottering about"

Answer (score 1):

I think "laze around" or "lounge about" are quite appropriate for the situation.

For instance, one could say : " On Sundays, I like to laze around the house instead of going out."

Comment: Doing chores is not lazing or lounging about.